# Why don't I see pingbacks?

Tags: pingbacks

I installed two WordPress instances on my site. One is wp1.site.com and the other is wp2.site.com. Now, I made a post on wp1 and then linked to it on wp2. I didn't see anything about pingbacks. I tried several pages/posts and saw no pingbacks.

Why? Where should I be seeing them, and why don't I see them? I saw someone mention "enabled for that post" and I checked if there are any post settings for pingback. I didn't see any. I just left the defaults and notice pingbacks were set to enable by default in my settings.

What's the problem here?

-edit- I see pingbacks if I link to a post on my site but not from either site to the other.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you link the sites. Wordpress is very particular.

If you link it with `http://...` at the beginning, then Wordpress will generate a pingback. If you do a relative link, then Wordpress will nto generate a pingback.

Whether this applies to subdomains as much as to cross-domains, I can't say. But, try linking them with full liks (`http://...`) to see what happens.

Also, make sure you have some pingback servers under `Settings` > `Writing` (`Update Services` section), and make sure you have `Allow link notifications from other blogs (pingbacks and trackbacks.)` enabled in `Settings` > `Discussion`.

Comment: I have only the default `http://rpc.pingomatic.com/`. What bothers me is if i use http://www.solitude.dk/ping/client.php?method=pingback.ping and write a dummy page on my server the pingback will work and i can accept it on wordpress. However linking from my other site does not automatically send the pingback.

Comment: But really i only set up wordpress cause 1) I wanted to make sure my php setup was working 2) I wanted to test the pingback on my site. php is working and that link does the pingback stuff so really i dont need to test with wordpress anymore